# Get value of an input type Range

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, range

I have this code:

```
<p class="slider1">Your approximate total debt: 
  <output name="slider_output1" id="slider_output1" for="form_slider1">0</output><br>                                                   
  <input type="range" class="form_slider1" name="form_slider1" id="form_slider1"
   value="0" min="0" max="60000" step="100" 
   oninput="slider_output1.value=form_slider1.value" 
   onchange="slider_output1.value=value"/>  
                                                                                                                                                           
</p>
```

I need to get the range/slider value for condition statement.
I tried using jQuery:

```
var slider1 = $("form_slider1").val();
```

but I got "undefined" when I alert the value.

```
alert(slider1);
```

Thank you guys in advance!

Comment: Try this: `var slider1 = $(".form_slider1").val();`

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
var slider1 = $(".form_slider1").val();
```

Answer (score 4):

javascript

**Replace the object with your element object and the eventCallback with your event(onclick for example)**

```
object.eventCallback=function(){
var r = document.getElementById('form_slider1').value;
alert(r);
};
```

jquery

```
var slider1 = $(".form_slider1").val();
```

This is regarding your comment

```
<input type="range" id="r" min="1" max="20">
<input type="submit" id="sub">

<script>
var r1=document.getElementById("sub");
r1.onclick=function(){
var r = document.getElementById('r').value;
if(r>10){
    alert("You crossed the half of it");
}
else alert("Value less than 10");
};
</script>
```

You can give your own conditions if you want (eq r==20 alert("the peak"));

Comment: Thanks! :)

By the way additional question,

How can I add a validation for this html5 input type range?
It should not be 0. How can I add a warning message, like the default validation messages on other html5 input types?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
 var slider1 = $("#form_slider1").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

From your code we can find that the *class name* and *id* of `input` component is same: **form_slider1**.

So, if you want use id to get this element's value, you should use this
`var slider1 = $("#form_slider1").val();`.

if you want to use class to get this element's value, you should use this
`var slider1 = $(".form_slider1").val();`